# Why does Eve die in Mass Effect 3 even though i saved maelons data

Tags: mass-effect-3

I saved the data to cure the genophage but eve still dies when i play through the mission. I saved the data in three previous times i played the trilogy  from the first game to the last and she always dies. Why does that happen?

Comment: Did you disarm the bomb Cerberus re-armed that the Turians had brought? if you don't she is later killed in the blast

Comment: also, I think you need to go down and talk to her after every mission, there are some dialog that may or may not be important (I talked to her every time and got the extra dialog and she survived in my playthrough).

Comment: @z' Certainly not, I never talked to her, still managed to save her. You need to disarm the bomb in time and keep in secret that the tower was sabotaged. Mordin will notice it before he dies.